# Trying to create UIImage returns: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have the following bit of code with a breakpoint on every line.  It hits the line that starts `var image : UIImage` and then it crashes with the nil error.  I have a file called Saturation.png.  I've tried it without the extension as well as using `named` instead of `contentsOfFile`

Nothing I try will get past that line.

```
func addSubviews() {
    if(filter != nil) {
    var image : UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Saturation.png")!
    let view = UIImageView(image: image)
    contentView.addSubview(view)

    let filterNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 66, 66, 20))
    filterNameLabel.text = filter.name!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("Amount", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    filterNameLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    filterNameLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
    filterNameLabel.highlightedTextColor = tintColor
    filterNameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    contentView.addSubview(filterNameLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: check the condition ==nil (do nothing), else start your work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  What should I check to see if it's nil?  The UIImage?  Why would it be nil?  Does this instantiate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentsOfFile:` requires a full path to yhe image, not just a file name, it won't go and do a search for you as that search could be over a massive set of directories and files. You need to get the full path, probably using `NSBundle` depending on what Nd where the file is.

Comment: As I said though I tried named as well.  This file is in the root folder of the app.  They were originally in a separate folder.  I moved them to the root to see if that would fix it.

Comment: Moved how? Are they copied as part of the build? Can you get the path with NSBundle? Did you clean and retry? Named is likely th correct solution, but doesn't search all folders